# Validate CAS token from external application

Tags: cas

I have an application protected by CAS. I am going to provide a link to another application (SAML IDP) and that application is not protected by CAS. So i have to pass the CAS token from my application to the IDP and IDP has to validate that token with CAS and get the user. Problem is that whenever i try to validate CAS token (already validated by my application) "ServiceTicket [XX] has expired". I am using the URL /serviceValidate and the CAS version is 3.5.2. Is there a way the token can be kept alive for validating multiple times? or the solution is to protect the IDP under CAS and generate a new token whenever i want to redirect to IDP

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve by generating a service ticket for the IDP. But we will not be able to validate the ticket multiple times
1. Passed the IDP URL as the service parameter to the cas /login url
2. Called the serviceValidate with that ticket from IDP to validate the ticket